# Resolver promesa con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promesas, async-await

Estoy tratando de comparar el resultado de una funcion que devuelve true o false para usar en una condicion `if (await (isUser(id)) == true)`.

```
$('#add').click(async function(e){
        let id = document.getElementById('input')
        if (await (isUser(id)) == true){
          ....


function isUser(id) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/isUser/'+id+'/',
                datatype: 'JSON',
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true 
                },
                success: function(result){
                    resolve(result.data == true);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que veo el error no viene de esa función, ¿podrías subir la parte del código en donde llamas a la función `isUser`?

EDIT:

`await` sólo puede ser usado en funciones asíncronas, por lo que debes agregar el `async` en la función, debería quedar así:

```
$('#add').click(async function(e){
    let id = document.getElementById('input').getAttribute('data-id');
    if (await (isUser(id)) == true){
      ....
```

Comment: Si no hace nada entonces pueden estar pasando dos cosas: 1- La solicitud a la API no termina de cargar. 2- El valor devuelto por la función `isUser(id)` quizás no sea un 'true' como se espera en la condición. Haz un log de lo que devuelve la función para ver qué está devolviendo